# Risk neutral pricing in incomplete markets

Tags: stochastic-processes, finance

let's consider a stochastic volatility model for the stock price under the objective probability measure $P$ of the form
\begin{equation} \label{eq:system_loc_stoch_vol}
\begin{cases}
dS_t=\mu S_t dt+ F(Y_t)  S_tdW_t \\
S_0=s_0 >0\\
dY_t= (m-Y_t )dt+ \nu  dB_t \\
Y_0=y_0 \in \mathbb{R}
\end{cases}
\end{equation} This leads to an incomplete market.

In fact by Girsanov theorem we can build a family of risk neutral measures $\{Q^\gamma\}_\gamma$ for any bounded $\gamma$.

In this way under $Q^\gamma$ we have that the process $e^{-rt}S_t$ is an $\mathcal{F}_t$-martingale where $\mathcal{F}_t$ is the filtration generated by $(W_t,B_t)$.
Then $Q^\gamma$ is a family of risk neutral meausures and by the second fundamental theorem of asset pricing this is an incomplete market.

Instead from the first fundamental theorem of asset pricing we have that there is no arbitrage opportunity (or better the NFLVR holds).

Now take a $T$-claim $\Psi=\Psi(S_T)$. My question is: why the pricing formula for $\Psi$ is the following? $$V_t=\mathbb{E}^{Q^\gamma}[e^{-r(T-t)}\Psi(S_T)|\mathcal{F}_t]$$
How can we show it?

In a complete market the formula is correct by a replicating argument, but in an incomplete market why is it correct?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: It is not correct or incorrect, people just define the option that way. There is not rigorous argument as in B-S. There is still an incentive to do so because it guarantees that there is no arbitrage opportunities in the (extended) market formed by the three assets: bond, stock and option and that's a desirable requirement.

Comment: I'm missing the following passage: by means of Girsanov I build a risk neutral measure $Q^\gamma$  in the market composed by the stock and bond only. So in the extended market (when we add the option) I have no guarantees that there is no arbitrage. is it correct? How can I build it in the extended market?

Comment: In my opinion the sentence: "So in the extended market (when we add the option) I have no guarantees that there is no arbitrage" is not correct. If we define the option price process by the risk-neutral valuation formula using any $Q^\gamma,$ you won't have arbitrage opportunities. The problem is that you can not hedge the option. Some people include a second option with a different maturity to complete the market. (I think the mathematics in incomplete markets have holes. Practitioners use the same tools from complete markets because it's useful but the theory is not as consistent as in BS).

Comment: with that sentence I mean that we need to show that there is no arbitrage in the extended market when we use that pricing formula. How can you show it?

Comment: If $X$ is a $L^1$-integrable random variable, then the process defined as $V_t=\mathbb{E}[X|\mathcal{F}_t], 0 \leq t \leq T$ is a UI-martingale.

Comment: You deleted the comment, but what you wrote before was correct. We already know that the discounted stock price process is a $Q^\gamma$-martingale. So in order to not have arbitrage opportunities in the extended market, we just have to show that the discounted option price process is also a $Q^\gamma$-martingale. To show that you can use my comment above, that it's a well-known fact.

Comment: Yes I see. thank you very much.

Comment: You're welcome.